# JavaScript: invalid token

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando  borrar un formulario, después limpiar el titulo y añadir otro titulo y añadir una serie de input checkbox, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
  $('#btnActividades').click(function() {

        $('#formulario').remove()
        $("#titulo").empty()
        $("#titulo").append("Tiempo disponible: ")
        $("#canjeador").append("
            
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4378" value="4378" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="221"> Factoría
                Digital: Industria 4.0 (240 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4308" value="4308" mins="270" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="220">
                Transformación Digital - ERP Inteligente (270 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4286" value="4286" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="219"> Cómo
                Potenciar el Liderazgo (180 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4340" value="4340" mins="225" class="eventos-minutos"
                    wfd-id="218"> Encuentro de empresas andaluzas (225 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4388" value="4388" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="217"> Oportunidades
                del Entorno Digital (240 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4403" value="4403" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="216"> Costes
                transporte marítimo internacional (240 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4407" value="4407" mins="120" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="215"> FP Sector
                Aeroespacial (120 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4395" value="4395" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="214"> Presentación
                Tactiómetro 2019 (180 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4402" value="4402" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="213"> Gemelo
                Digital (180 mins)</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4439" value="4439" mins="90" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="212"> Cómo ganar
                dinero con tu blog y redes (90 mins)</p>
        ")

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que se usa "" en vez de '', y se interpreta el segundo " como cierre

```
return '<div class="wpb_wrapper" wfd-id="134"><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4378" value="4378" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="221"> Factoría Digital: Industria 4.0 (240 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4308" value="4308" mins="270" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="220"> Transformación Digital - ERP Inteligente (270 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4286" value="4286" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="219"> Cómo Potenciar el Liderazgo (180 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4340" value="[object HTMLInputElement]" mins="225" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="218"> Encuentro de empresas andaluzas (225 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4388" value="4388" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="217"> Oportunidades del Entorno Digital  (240 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4403" value="4403" mins="240" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="216"> Costes transporte marítimo internacional (240 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4407" value="4407" mins="120" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="215"> FP Sector Aeroespacial (120 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4395" value="4395" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="214"> Presentación Tactiómetro 2019 (180 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4402" value="4402" mins="180" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="213"> Gemelo Digital (180 mins)</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="evento-4439" value="4439" mins="90" class="eventos-minutos" wfd-id="212"> Cómo ganar dinero con tu blog y redes  (90 mins)</p></div>'
```

Comment: ¿Es una respuesta?

Comment: actualizado, que te parece ahora?

Comment: Mejor, ya se explica el fallo y como arreglarlo